# Flutter swipe on screen to display new page

Tags: android, flutter, dart, menu, drag

I am still learning flutter but want to make something a bit more complicated now. I would like to create something like the Draggable Main Apps menu in Android.

While it's possible to use a stack with a GestureDetector on top it's probably not the most performant solution and also I'd like to use routing as it's a new screen.

While I don't have too much experience with the different types of routes, when I use PopUpRoute for example I lose the scroll gesture of the previous screen that controls the animation.

Would appreciate if someone could give me an idea how to approach this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but maybe one  of these will give you a direction:

- You might want to checkout `BottomSheet` widget (it might save you some coding).
- If it's supposed to be draggable from the previous/current screen, you probably will need some gesture detection to trigger the slide and then use `Stack`, I see nothing wrong with using it, or maybe `Overlay`.
- If it's supposed to be a new "screen" with possibility to see the previous one underneath, you might want to read about `Modal`s (there is even this beauty already available `showModalBottomSheet<T>()` [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)).
- And if it's supposed to be a new actual screen, then you might checkout route transitions [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation).

Hope this helps, good luck!